# F# WebApi return properly formatted json from a discriminated union

Tags: f#, json.net, asp.net-web-api2

I was wondering what the easiest way would be to return clean json from the result of a discriminated union in WebApi?  This use case is for business logic only and not used for http errors, etc - those get handled in the pipeline and get returned to user as usual (404, 500, etc)

For example:

```
type ServiceResult<'a> = { Message:string; Payload:'a }

type ServiceResponse<'a> =
    | Success of ServiceResult<'a>
    | Fail of ServiceResult<string>
```

Returns Either:

```
{
  "Case": "Fail",
  "Fields": [
    {
      "Message": "Error performing business logic, your x is not in the y.",
      "Payload": "I just couldnt do it"
    }
  ]
}
```

...or...

```
{
  "Case": "Success",
  "Fields": [
    {
      "Message": "",
      "Payload": { "FirstName": "Johnny", "LastName":"Smith" }
    }
  ]
}
```

Where I would like to have only the service result returned like:

```
{
  "Message": "",
  "Payload": { "FirstName": "Johnny", "LastName":"Smith" }
}
```

... or ...

```
{
  "Message": "Error during operation due to spite.",
  "Payload": "I just couldnt do it"
}
```

I have tried IdiomaticDuConverter:
https://gist.github.com/isaacabraham/ba679f285bfd15d2f53e

but it didnt work.  The closest i have seen is Microsoft.FSharpLu.Json but it doesnt have a MediaTypeFormatter to plug into the pipeline.

I know i can use Lu and create my own MediaTypeFormatter but I feel like there has to be an easier way (like some Json.Net option I am missing).

Can you point me in the right direction?

thanks :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

While there may be corner cases where the return representation you're asking about is the correct design, in general **this isn't good HTTP API design**. ASP.NET Web API returns HTTP responses, so the implication of returning

```
{
  "Success": false,
  "Message": "Error during operation due to spite.",
  "Payload": "I just couldnt do it"
}
```

is that this value is being returned as part of a `200 OK` response. This puts an extra burden on clients, because they now have to handle not only HTTP errors (which can still happen), but also can't trust that `200 OK` actually meant success.

Instead, if there's an error, return [the appropriate HTTP status code](https://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec10.html).

This also solves the problem, and makes your F# code easy to write. In a Controller, you'd basically do something like this:

```
member this.Get() =
    let result = // produce the result somehow...
    match result with
    | Success x -> this.Ok x :> IHttpActionResult
    | Fail msg  -> this.BadRequest msg :> IHttpActionResult
```

For simplicity's sake, this example returns `400 Bad Request` on a `Fail` case, but if this case represents an internal error, perhaps `500 Internal Server Error` would be more appropriate.

Comment: I updated my question to be a little more clear.  The success/failure is not http/server/rest failures, they are business logic failures.  However you fixed my issue, i just needed to cast the result to IHttpActionResult.

Answer (score 1):

You can write a [custom JSON.NET serializer](http://blog.maskalik.com/asp-net/json-net-implement-custom-serialization/) for your `ServiceResponse` type that would simply skip the case label and delegate serialization to the nested `ServiceResult`.

The real question here is why do you even have this problem? You already carry the success/failure status in the record, the DU doesn't offer any additional information. What's more, with the setup you have, you can easily represent seemingly undesirable states like this:

```
Success <| { Success = false; Message = "necktie"; Payload = "bacon" }
```

Why not just drop it and pass around the record only, avoiding the serialization problem altogether?